# How to create a macro for object instantiation in Objective-C/ANSI C

Tags: c, objective-c

I hope I'm wording my question properly, but what I'm trying to do is actually rather trivial.

I have a bunch of code with static object instantiation that looks like this:

```
Foo *aFoo1 = [[[Foo alloc] init] autorelease];
[anArray addObject:aFoo1];
Foo *aFoo2 = [[[Foo alloc] init] autorelease];
[anArray addObject:aFoo2];
```

I simply want to move all of that instantiation + population of anArray into a separate header file, and just include the header file where it's needed without the overhead of creating a new class to manage these instantiations. I just want to include the header file and get access to anArray once it's done adding all of the above objects and stuff it somewhere else. Is there anyway I can turn the above into a macro? Ideally I'll have all of this in a database soon, query the db, and instantiate the result set. Either way, I'm curious what the answer to this is in the format it's currently written in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My thought are to put the setup in a C function. You'd probably want to use two files:

```
//  Extra.h
// new file with descriptive header
NSArray* setupMyArray( ... );
```

-

```
//
// Extra.m
NSArray* setupMyArray( ... )
{
    NSMutableArray * anArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:0];
    // code to build array...
    //...
    return anArray;
}
```

Though I believe you'd be getting in to sketchy territory here. With Objective-C you are using an object orientated language. With C, you're not. It sounds like you want to build your objects in C and then use them in your class.

Comment: Kind of. Your .h file would contain the function def. The implementation would go in a .c file.

Comment: Don't think the compiler will take objective-c code in a .c file.

Comment: You can use a regular .m file. Objective-C inherits from C, so creating a regular "c-style" function in a .m file is perfectly valid.

Comment: @Frank: +1: You have the right answer here, and it's not sketchy territory at all. All you need to watch out for is proper memory management.

Comment: @Frank: I took the liberty of changing it for you. I hope you don't mind :)

Comment: @eJames: Thanks for the guidance. I wasn't quite sure about this as I had never done it. I did hear about it theoretically which is where I got the idea... Again, thank you.

Comment: @eJames: Of course I don't mind. I think this is one of the strong points of stackoverflow. It helps prevent bad or misguided information from becoming popular...

Answer (score 3):

You could use the following:

```
#define CREATE_INSTANCE_AND_ADD_TO_ARRAY(TYPE, NAME, ARRAY) \
        TYPE * NAME = [[[TYPE alloc] init] autorelease];    \
        [ARRAY addObject:NAME]
```

Called like so:

```
CREATE_INSTANCE_AND_ADD_TO_ARRAY(Foo, aFoo1, anArray);
CREATE_INSTANCE_AND_ADD_TO_ARRAY(Foo, aFoo2, anArray);
...
```

Comment: Plus, if you didn't care about the intermediate variables, couldn't you do something like `#define CREATE_INSTANCE_AND_ADD_TO_ARRAY(TYPE, ARRAY) [ARRAY addObject:[[[TYPE alloc] init] autorelease]]`

Comment: Good point. I just assumed that the intermediates were important to the code.

Answer (score 0):

Check the text macros in Xcode under Edit > Text Macros > Objective-C.

(You can even assign them keyboard shortcuts in Xcode preferences)